# Get text from Label inside an Item template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently pulling from the database and have the 2 labels showing the correct information. However I want to use these labels in the behind code but they are not showing up for me. The reason I need this in the behind code is so I can insert the email address to the recipient email.

Below is the front end showing the Item template and SQL Datasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="userCourse" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT tblCourse.courseTitle, tblCourse.advisorOfStudiesID, tblPersonalInfo.firstName, tblPersonalInfo.lastName, tblPersonalInfo.email FROM tblCourse INNER JOIN tblAdvisorOfStudies ON tblCourse.advisorOfStudiesID = tblAdvisorOfStudies.advisorOfStudiesID INNER JOIN tblUsers ON tblAdvisorOfStudies.userID = tblUsers.userID INNER JOIN tblPersonalInfo ON tblUsers.personalInfoID = tblPersonalInfo.personalInfoID WHERE (tblCourse.courseID = @userID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="userID" Name="userID"></asp:SessionParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="userCourse">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="aosemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="aosname" hidden runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Below is the behind code in which I want to get the labels text

```
private bool SendEmail()
{
    string recipient = aosemail; //AOS Email textbox should go here
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("CSC3047@gmail.com", recipient);
    mm.Subject = "Student has chosen Manual Enrollment Process!";
    //AOS name textbox will be here
    mm.Body = "Hi "   + aosename+ "<br><br>This is a quick email to inform you that " + Name.Text.ToString() + " has chosen the manual enrollment process. The reason we are emailing you is that you are their Advisor of Studies. Please email the user on " + Email.Text.ToString() + " <br><br>Regards";
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
    NetworkCred.UserName = "*************";
    NetworkCred.Password = "*********";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mm);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does it mean 'labels behind the code'?

Comment: `string recipient = aosemail;` Are you using `aosemail.Text`?

Comment: @TamasRev So the label is on the front end .aspx  I want to be able to get the text of the label in the behind code but i am unable to call it in the .aspx.cs file as its inside an Item Template

Comment: @Nathangrad cant be called like this as it is in an Item Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `FindContol` to search for the Labels in the ListView. And since there could be more than one you have to use an index, just like an Array.

```
int index = 0;

Label aosemail = ListView1.Items[index].FindControl("aosemail") as Label;
Label aosname = ListView1.Items[index].FindControl("aosname") as Label;

string body = "Hi " + aosname.Text + "<br><br>" + aosemail.Text;
```

Comment: Thankyou!! I was stuck on this for about 4 hours last night.