# passing label templatefield value to vb.net function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, templatefield

I have this gridview with a templateField like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase"  Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase"  Text='<%# Bind("age") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and I have this html hyperlink that suppose to pass **name and Age** to both **onServerClick** function

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a id="btn_Approve" onserverclick="Approve_Click" style="font-size:12px;color:Green;text-decoration: none;" runat="server" href='#'>Approve</a>     
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <a id="btn_Update" onserverclick="Update_Click" style="font-size:12px;text-decoration: none;" runat="server">Update</a>                                
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

can anyone guide me on how can I pass those labelId to code behind function

thanks.

Comment: Are you want to pass both `name` and `age` values with `onserverclick` for each anchor tag? You can create a custom attribute for them and pass it using `Attributes("attributename")` by mentioning `HtmlAnchor`, also don't forget to add `runat="server"` too.

Comment: yes, i want to pass either one or both ids, I don't get it what you mean by the way, could u give some example?in code form, I'm totally new in asp actually.

Comment: An example using `Eval()`: `<a id="btn_Approve" runat="server" onserverclick='Approve(<%# Eval("name")%>,<%# Eval("age")%>)' style="font-size:12px;color:Green;text-decoration: none;" href='#'>Approve</a>`. Other anchor link should have same parameters with different event handler method.

Comment: its gave me **Error 26 Identifier expected.** on that line

Comment: Make sure the function/method name is exactly same as you're defined and all parameters are properly declared. How you define `Approve_Click` and `Update_Click` methods? They're currently not shown on your question.

Comment: I have change my funtion from `Protected Sub Approve_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)` to this `Public Sub Approve(ByVal nameAs String, ByVal age As String)` but still receive **Identifier Expected** on this `<a id="btn_Approve" runat="server" onserverclick='Approve('<%#Eval("name").ToString()+","+Eval("age").toString()%>')' style="font-size:12px;color:Green;text-decoration: none;" href='#'>Approve</a>`, what was that mean?

Comment: How about using `DataBinder.Eval` like this: `<a id="btn_Approve" runat="server" onserverclick='<%= Approve(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "age")) %>' style="font-size:12px;color:Green;text-decoration: none;" href='#'>Approve</a>`? Sounds like multiple single quotes in the anchor markup confuses the code editor.

Comment: tried already, same error, I believe it shouldn't be a problem if I just pass that value to back-end of the same page, right? I mean the hyperlinks is in _process.aspx_ and pass to _process.aspx.vb_?

Comment: The code above intended to pass into VB function which defined inside .vb file that has same name as the ASPX page. If you put the functions in another .vb file, probably you need to reference its location.

Comment: by other means, its should have not be a problems at all, but I still couldn't get the value of those label. and what make me wonder is,when I try to call **lblName.Text** its gave me this error **`Name 'lblName' is not declared.`**

Comment: Well, probably you need this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976745/get-text-from-label-inside-an-item-template. The `lblName` is located inside `ItemTemplate`, hence use `FindControl("lblName")` to get its text value.

Comment: thanks for your guide, now I've manage to the value if I do this `For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.AutoPopulateGridView.Rows
            Dim label As Label = DirectCast(AutoPopulateGridView.FindControl("lblName"), Label)
            Dim text As String = label.Text
            MsgBox("username : " + text)
        Next` but if i just call the `Dim label As Label = DirectCast(AutoPopulateGridView.FindControl("lblName"), Label)` its gave me a nullReferenceExceptions.